# Wordpress Include jQuery UI Checkboxradio for frontend theme functions.php

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I have a bit of a problem with jQuery UI & jQuery theme not loading.

Im using the latest Wordpress 4.6.
Using Functions.php within my theme folder, ive added this code:

```
    function jquery_frontend_scripts() {
        global $wp_scripts; 
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-core');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-checkboxradio'); 

        $queryui = $wp_scripts->query('jquery-ui-core'); 

        $url = "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/".$queryui->ver."/themes/base/jquery-ui.css";
        wp_enqueue_style('jquery-ui-base', $url, false, null);
    }

    if (!is_admin()) add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jquery_frontend_scripts');
```

On a contact7 page within wordpress admin ive added:

```
    <script>
     jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( "input" ).checkboxradio({
          icon: false
        });
    } );
    </script>

    <legend>Välj belopp: </legend>
    <label for="radio-50">50 kr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-50" id="radio-50">
    <label for="radio-200">200 kr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-200" id="radio-200">
    <label for="radio-500">500 kr</label>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-500" id="radio-500">
```

That function is being called. So I guess there must be something wrong with jQuery UI or the jQuery Theme not loading correctly.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-checkboxradio');

I dont see the dependency in the reference 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Is it not

> jquery-ui-button

or

> jquery-ui-form

Comment: Indeed, it's not there. The question is why ? and how can we include it in Wordpress ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with specifying the source of the script, passing it as a second parameter of the function `wp_enqueue_script`?

See the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Comment: Thanks! I just tried it but no effect :(

With: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js'); and wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', '//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js');`

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit late, but in case you did not find the answer, your url for the jquery-ui "base" style is incorrect.  The current version of jquery ui in wordpress is 1.11.4. If you go to //ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/base/jquery-ui.css, you get a 404.  I don't see that the base style is available through http://code.jquery.com/ui/ with version 1.11.4, but it is available for version 1.12.1.  So I would suggest selecting a different style or seeing if the newest stable version of the base style works.